# When/how to change python sys.prefix from /usr when site-packages is in /usr/local?

Tags: python, configuration, path, package

If I'm following https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html correctly, I need to either move the site-packages directory to /usr/lib/python2.7 or change sys.prefix to /usr/local.

The former seems wrong. For the latter the options I can find are to edit site.py directly or to re-install python. Is editing site.py considered too hacky, or is it a standard-ish thing to do? (ETA: I would think it's a standard thing to do, as that's what it's for. Guess I'm really asking if that's the best choice in this instance.)

Or am I overlooking another option?

/usr/lib vs /usr/local/lib:

```
auto@virgo:/etc/apache2$ ls -ld /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages: No such file or directory

auto@virgo:/etc/apache2$ ls -ld /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Aug 29  2013 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

python sys.prefix:

```
auto@virgo:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.prefix
/usr
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create either `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` and append to `site.PREFIXES`

```
import site
SITEPKGS = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
site.addsitedir(SITEPKGS)
site.PREFIXES += ['/usr/local']
```

assuming `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is the path to your `/usr/local` site packages.

From [site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) docs:

> After these path manipulations, an attempt is made to import a module named `sitecustomize`, which can perform arbitrary site-specific customizations. It is typically created by a system administrator in the site-packages directory. If this import fails with an `ImportError` exception, it is silently ignored. If Python is started without output streams available, as with `pythonw.exe` on Windows (which is used by default to start IDLE), attempted output from `sitecustomize` is ignored. Any exception other than `ImportError` causes a silent and perhaps mysterious failure of the process.
>
> After this, an attempt is made to import a module named `usercustomize`, which can perform arbitrary user-specific customizations, if `ENABLE_USER_SITE` is true. This file is intended to be created in the user site-packages directory (see below), which is part of `sys.path` unless disabled by `-s`. An `ImportError` will be silently ignored.

**Note**: Where `usercustomize.py` should go depends on the value of `site.USER_SITE`, which on Linux for Python-2.7 is `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

**Note**: Also `sitecustomize.py` would be placed by an *administrator* in the site packages folder found in `sys.prefix`.

Other options would be to set environment variables:

- set [`PYTHONUSERBASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE) to `/usr/local` which will switch the location of the user's base Python directory from `~/.local` to whatever you set it to. **Note**: This would disable your packages installed into `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

  ```
    export PYTHONUSERBASE=/usr/local
  ```
- set [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to *prepend* `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which would add it to `sys.path`.

  ```
    export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
  ```

Environment variables can be exported in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` settings, added to `/etc/environment` to make them system-wide, or you can simple precede your Python interpreter call with the desired environment variables:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages python
```

Comment: Why `import os`?